# Make first word in macro bold

Tags: macros

I have the following use-case:

```
\cmd{cp \opt{r} \marg{from} \marg{to}}
```

This should typeset a UNIX command for a manual. I’d like the actual command (here, `cp`) to be typeset in bold while the rest of the command line is typeset normally. Now, I could obviously just write something along the following lines:

```
\cmd{\textbf{cp} \opt{r} \marg{from} \marg{to}}
```

… but I’d prefer if this were possible automatically. I thought of two approaches but cannot get either to work:

1. Make everything bold, cancel bold for nested commands:

   ```
   \newcommand*\cmd[1]{%
       \texttt{\textbf{#1}}
   }
   \newcommand*\opt[1]{%
       \undobf{-#1}
   }
   ```

   … problem: how would `\undobf` look like? `\textrm` isn’t appropriate here since I need to preserve the `tt` style.
2. Define a TeX command containing a space in its arguments:

   ```
   \newcommand*\cmd[1]{%
       \texttt{\setcmd#1}
   }
   \def\setcmd#1 #2{%
       \textbf{#1} #2
   }
   ```

   But this doesn’t work at all, probably because I’m botching the syntax. But even once the syntax is fixed, this still won’t work for cases where I provide no arguments/options for a command (e.g. `\cmd{pwd}`).

Comment: Should it only take one argument? With e.g. two arguments you could do something like `\newcommand{\cmd}[2]{\textbf{#1} #2}`

Comment: @Tom Hmpf. I should have seen that solution myself. I’d still prefer if TeX could parse the argument itself (in fact I also dislike the `\opt` and `\marg` macros and if I had more time and my TeX weren’t so rusty then I’d fix it so that the usage would be as follows: `\cmd{cp -r from to}` … but that’s a story for another day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One could use the usual TeX/LaTeX programming to decide if the first word has something after it and then choose the right branch.

With LaTeX3 functions it's much easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgcursor} % clone of Courier

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cmd}{ m }
 {
  \krudolph_split_cmd:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \krudolph_split_cmd:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__krudolph_cmd_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__krudolph_cmd_seq \l__krudolph_cmd_tl
  \group_begin:
  \normalfont\ttfamily
  \textbf{ \l__krudolph_cmd_tl } ~
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l__krudolph_cmd_seq { ~ } { ~ } { ~ }
  \group_end:
 }
\seq_new:N \l__krudolph_cmd_seq
\tl_new:N \l__krudolph_cmd_tl 
\ExplSyntaxOff

% missing definitions
\newcommand{\opt}[1]{-#1}
\newcommand{\marg}[1]{<#1>}


\begin{document}
\cmd{cp \opt{r} \marg{from} \marg{to}}

\cmd{pwd}
\end{document}
```

The argument is split at spaces; then the first element is detached for being printed in boldface; the rest is printed in medium weight, separated by spaces.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, before I can start using this I need to use LaTeX3. Ah well, that day will surely come.

Answer (score 9):

You had the syntax correct for (2) but if you look in the log file it probably said

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/cmtt/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/n' tried instead on input line 18.
```

That is, the standard TeX fonts don't have bold typewriter so although you correctly asked for that you got normal weight instead.

If you don't want `cp` to be in monospace I think you the following where you just add the grouping in your user command and switch to tt after the bold:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\opt#1{{[#1]}}
\def\marg#1{{\char`\{#1\char`\}}}

\newcommand*\cmd[1]{{\setcmd#1 }}

\def\setcmd#1 {%
    \textbf{#1} \ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

\cmd{cp \opt{r} \marg{from} \marg{to}}

\cmd{pwd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I’m loading `courier` so the bold font is available. Sorry, I should have been more explicit in the error message, which is along the lines of “use of `\setcmd` doesn’t match its definition”. It works after using extra braces around the invocation, as in your example. However, it predictably still fails for `\cmd{pwd}`.

Comment: That's why the MWE should always be a complete docuement. If you got that error (which I didn't when I ran your example) it was called when there was no explicit space in the input stream, if you need to make sure there is a space, so `\newcommand*\cmd[1]{{\setcmd#1 }}` with a space after `#1`.

Comment: I totally agree. I omitted the MWE because I wasn’t actually fishing for a correction of an error, I just wanted to show my thoughts about an approach, i.e. I’d considered my code as pseudo code rather than almost-working TeX.